# Unable to add Android platform in Meteor after following instructions

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, meteor

I receive this dreaded "error message" every time I try to add Android as a platform using `meteor install-sdk android`

> Please follow the installation instructions in the mobile guide:
>   http://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#installing-prerequisites

I've went over the instructions several times and triple-checked everything each time. To prove this I'll outline exactly what I did and hopefully somebody can reproduce my problem or catch something I've missed.

First, I installed Android Studio and dependancies using Ubuntu Make

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
umake android
```

Then, I ran `android-studio` to complete the installation.

After this I explicitly installed SDK 23 by navigating to `~/Android/Sdk/tools` and running `./android` (the SDK Manager)

I made the end of my `.bashrc` file look like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/eric/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
echo "Wake up Neo."
```

The `echo` at the end verifies that this runs when I open a terminal. I have also verified the $PATH variable by testing it in the terminal.

`/usr/lib/jvm/default-java` is a symlink to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64` which is a symlink to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`. I tried all three and, as would be expected, got the same result each time. I consider this to be my "universe check" to verify that the universe isn't (completely) broken.

Please may somebody else reproduce this error; this is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1):

Meteor's `install-sdk` command is literally just a command that tells you to read the documentation. That's just what it does. Running `meteor add-platform android` (the next command the documentation says to run) works as expected after following these instructions.

Hopefully this helps somebody else who is just as confused. I'm going to post a related issue on the GitHub page.